# Grant Access for user to SqlLocalDB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I'm using C# Windows Forms application to connect to a SQL Server LocalDb database with this connection string:

```
DataSource(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlLocalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

When trying to connect to the database using this code:

```
Entitis db = new Entitis ();
db.Database.Connection.Open();
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Table1.ToList();
```

I get the following error:

> Login failed for user 'MyPC1\User1'.'

How could I fix that error ? Thanks

Comment: Add the user to SQL or create login credentials to use with DB

Comment: Could you explain more, please. What do you mean by adding the user to SQL ?

Comment: you need to create a user in sql.  And give the appropriate permissions from the db. Google how to add a user to sql it will give you the steps